# What are the common encoding parameters needed to concat losslessly mp4 videos with the ffmpeg concat demuxer?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

When I tried to concat mp4 videos with the ffmpeg concat demuxer, the resulting video was out of sync starting from the end of the first video.

Although I use the same video resolution, fps, 128k audio bit-rate, it wasn't sufficient :

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'WhatsApp_Video_2021-10-20_at_6.45.53_AM-128kb.mp4':
  Duration: 00:00:24.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4098 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3970 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 19200 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'TOUT_N_ETAIT_PAS_ENCORE_ACCOMPLI_A_LA_CROIX_DR_N_GUESSAN_MICHEL__136-140__BzQKTvNYwlg__youtube_com.mp4':
  Duration: 00:51:43.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1932 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1796 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
```

What are the common encoding parameters needed to concat losslessly mp4 videos the the ffmpeg concat demuxer ?

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603/

Comment: @Gyan Thanks man. God bless you.